# A timeline of schools and theories

Tags: reference-request, history-of-linguistics

Is there an academic source for a timeline of schools and theories of linguistics? I can’t find any good source.

This is sort of what I’m looking for (https://prezi.com/d2261rzsz3ah/history-of-linguistics/) but there are no references.

Comment: What do you mean by "timeline"? A timeline as I understand it a grade school graphic for crudely stating when events happened, not an academic tool. There is a rather substantial sub-discipline "history of linguistics", which looks at how one idea relates over time to another, or what people promulgated what ideas, but it's a massive area of study. You can't even get a single summary picture of the history of the concept "floating tone", much less whole "schools of linguistics" like "OT", "GB", "wave-theory".

Comment: Here is one: https://www.uni-due.de/ELE/TL_HistoryOfLinguistics.htm And here is another: https://home.csulb.edu/~cwallis/382/readings/482/text/history_outline.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cl4Vm4LWxs0) interesting. It's a brief overview of some things in the book Battle in the Mind Fields by UChicago professor John Goldsmith, which happens to involve linguistics heavily. At the same time, it involves other disciplines-- as linguistics' history is not well understood without these pieces of the puzzle as well. It is also important to understand that there is not one history of linguistics, but many, and many interpretations. But you probably already knew that ;)

Also, see [this bibliography](https://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780199772810/obo-9780199772810-0186.xml).

Answer (score 2):

A pretty good one is this book

- Hans Arens: *Sprachwissenschaft. Der Gang ihrer Entwicklung von der Antike bis zur Gegenwart*. 2 Bde. 2. Aufl. (*Fischer Athenäum Taschenbücher*, 2077f). Athenäum Fischer Taschenbuch Verlag, Frankfurt 1974. ISBN 3-8072-2077-1

Unfortunately, it was written in 1974, so the end point is rather early.

As quick entry point for a search for more references there are these Wikipedia articles: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschichte_der_Sprachwissenschaft (in German) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_linguistics (in English)