# What is linguistics?

Tags: reference-request, textbooks

I would like to read a book similar to ["What is mathematics?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Is_Mathematics%3F), but about linguistics.
In other words, I would like to see a text that touches different branches of linguistics in an elementary but not boring way.

> Is there an example of such a book?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think "The Cambridge Encyclopedia of Language" by David Crystal is a good read in this respect.

You can also look at [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/44258/9781) and its answers for some more suggestions.

Comment: Precisely the book I was going to recommend.

Answer (score 2):

[*Teach yourself linguistics*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071429824) from the [*Teach yourself*](https://library.teachyourself.com/) series is a good introduction for laymen. Another useful source is  [*I-Language: An Introduction to Linguistics as Cognitive Science*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199660174).